# Dump or serialize object in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

console.log() does not serialize QML objects. I wonder how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample QML object to serialize?

Comment: @Nikita Krupenko, Please check my answer as I'm sure many QML programmers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate the serialization and deserialization of QML objects (which can also be utilized in C++), the [QtQuickStream](https://github.com/Roniasoft/QtQuickStream) provides robust functionality, serving as a potent tool for this purpose.

Comment: Seems one need to use QSObject as base class to use this module