# How to log Qt objects that are accessible by javascript in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I can successfully log properties of Qt objects in javascript:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    console.log(event.key)
}
```

But is it possible to log an objects and get see all of its members in one log?

With JavaScript objects in the Chrome dev tools I can do this:

```
var myObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
console.log(myObj) // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Can I do something similar with the event object in Qt QML?

Comment: Yes you can. Try to use forum search because this question has answered 100 times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293838/qml-list-all-object-members-properties-in-console